# Resize jQuery Content "drawer" after repopulated via JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a block of html that is a small button which, when clicked, opens down to reveal some content.

From within that content, there is a link which, when clicked, loads other content into the same container.

When that new content is dynamically loaded, I am trying to figure out how to make the container open further if the content is larger than original, without clicking it closed then open again to resize the divs.

https://jsfiddle.net/robarwebservices/k3s7o8tt/24/

Clicking the button will open a panel with content. Click the link in the content, which will load a larger piece of content, and notice that the content area doesn't grow with the new content when it is loaded... (but it does when you close and reopen the content panel via the button).

How can I achieve this?

Here is the code from the fiddle:

The HTML:

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="row cf">
  <span id="switch" class="rounded">open/close panel</span>
    <div id="wrapper" class="rounded cf">
      <div id="content">
        <p>"#content" gets <a id="repop" href="#" onclick=" document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = '<p>P1</p><p>P2</p><p>P3</p><p>P4</p><p>P5</p>';return false;">repopulated</a> via js</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The JS

```
$(document).on('click', '#switch', function () 
{

var w = $("#wrapper");
var h = $("#content");

if (w.hasClass('open')) {
    w.removeClass('open');
    w.height(0);
} else {
    w.addClass('open');
    w.height(h.outerHeight(true) + 50);
}

});
```

Relevant CSS

```
.cf:after, .cf:before {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}
.row::after, .row::before {
    display: table;
    content: " ";
    clear: both;
}
.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}
*, :after, :before {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}


#switch {
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
    padding: 7px;
}

#wrapper {
    background: #e0e0e0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: height 200ms;
    height: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the content box doesn't get any bigger is that its height is set by `w.height(h.outerHeight(true) + 50);` & `w.height(0)`

To get around this we should set the styles and let the class `.open` do the work

```
#wrapper {
  display: none;
}

.open#wrapper {
  height: auto
  display: block
}
```

then remove `w.height(h.outerHeight(true) + 50);` and  `w.height(0);`

```
if (w.hasClass('open')) {
    w.removeClass('open');
} else {
    w.addClass('open');
}
```

which means we can refactor this down to just

> `w.toggleClass('open');`

.

> working jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/k3s7o8tt/34/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, this a great simplification, and it achieves what I was trying to do. I believe, though, I have lost the transition effect on height... Can you suggest any way to retain that "sliding open/down" and "sliding closed/up" effect when opening and closing the container?

Comment: sorry abit busy this covers what you want to do though https://css-tricks.com/using-css-transitions-auto-dimensions/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/k3s7o8tt/84/ 've just done that quickly its not perfect though

Comment: This doesn't quite do it, I think because in my actual implementation, there is a delay between the click, and the data loading into it.  Thanks anyway